# Div overflow scroll not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've made a div layout that looks and works exactly as I want it to do, in all browsers (haven't tested Safari), but not Chrome (!?).

HTML:

```
<div class="app-wrapper">
  <div class="page-header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="page-content">
    <div class="component-container">
      <div class="list-container">
        <!-- lots of list items -->
      </div>
      <div class="content-container">
        <!-- lots of content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.app-wrapper
  height: 100%
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column

.page-header
  flex: 0 0 auto
  height: 80px

.page-content
  flex: 1 1 auto
  position: relative
  overflow: auto

.component-container
  display: flex
  height: 100%

.list-container
  height: 100%
  overflow: auto

.content-container
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  overflow: auto
```

[Here is a CodePen](https://codepen.io/mottosson/pen/KZpNwE)

Whats wrong and what can I do to make the list (yellow) and content (green) have their own overflow scroll like in all other browsers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give page content a specific height otherwise its children will take full 100% browser height.

```
.page-content {
     height: 100%;
     ...
```

Comment: Wow, I should probably take a break =P Thanks a lot, that did the trick!